# Can I open the URL automaticly when I scan with WebQR

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I am a programmer and I just made a simple webapp, with webview in Android studio. I have everything working except one thing. I used the WebQR set from LazarSoft. In my webapp part I have a file called webqr.js (found beneath) with the following content.

What I am trying to do is when a QR-code is scanned I want to open the result (if it is an URL) automatic in the same browser window. Now it just shows only the result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```html
var gCtx = null;
var gCanvas = null;
var c=0;
var stype=0;
var gUM=false;
var webkit=false;
var moz=false;
var v=null;

var imghtml='<div id="qrfile"><canvas id="out-canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>'+
    '<div id="imghelp">drag and drop a QRCode here'+
 '<br>or select a file'+
 '<input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"/>'+
 '</div>'+
'</div>';

var vidhtml = '<video id="v" autoplay></video>';

function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;
  if(files.length>0)
  {
 handleFiles(files);
  }
  else
  if(dt.getData('URL'))
  {
 qrcode.decode(dt.getData('URL'));
  }
}

function handleFiles(f)
{
 var o=[];
 
 for(var i =0;i<f.length;i++)
 {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
            gCtx.clearRect(0, 0, gCanvas.width, gCanvas.height);

   qrcode.decode(e.target.result);
        };
        })(f[i]);
        reader.readAsDataURL(f[i]); 
    }
}

function initCanvas(w,h)
{
    gCanvas = document.getElementById("qr-canvas");
    gCanvas.style.width = w + "px";
    gCanvas.style.height = h + "px";
    gCanvas.width = w;
    gCanvas.height = h;
    gCtx = gCanvas.getContext("2d");
    gCtx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
}


function captureToCanvas() {
    if(stype!=1)
        return;
    if(gUM)
    {
        try{
            gCtx.drawImage(v,0,0);
            try{
                qrcode.decode();
            }
            catch(e){       
                console.log(e);
                setTimeout(captureToCanvas, 500);
            };
        }
        catch(e){       
                console.log(e);
                setTimeout(captureToCanvas, 500);
        };
    }
}

function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}

function read(a)
{
    var html="<br>";
    if(a.indexOf("http://") === 0 || a.indexOf("https://") === 0)
        html+="<a target='_blank' href='"+a+"'>"+a+"</a><br>";
    html+="<b>"+htmlEntities(a)+"</b><br><br>";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=html;
} 

function isCanvasSupported(){
  var elem = document.createElement('canvas');
  return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext('2d'));
}
function success(stream) {
    if(webkit)
        v.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    else
    if(moz)
    {
        v.mozSrcObject = stream;
        v.play();
    }
    else
        v.src = stream;
    gUM=true;
    setTimeout(captureToCanvas, 500);
}
  
function error(error) {
    gUM=false;
    return;
}

function load()
{
 if(isCanvasSupported() && window.File && window.FileReader)
 {
  initCanvas(800, 600);
  qrcode.callback = read;
  document.getElementById("mainbody").style.display="inline";
        setwebcam();
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("mainbody").style.display="inline";
  document.getElementById("mainbody").innerHTML='<p id="mp1">QR code scanner for HTML5 capable browsers</p><br>'+
        '<br><p id="mp2">sorry your browser is not supported</p><br><br>'+
        '<p id="mp1">try <a href="http://www.mozilla.com/firefox"><img src="firefox.png"/></a> or <a href="http://chrome.google.com"><img src="chrome_logo.gif"/></a> or <a href="http://www.opera.com"><img src="Opera-logo.png"/></a></p>';
 }
}

function setwebcam()
{
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="- scanning -";
    if(stype==1)
    {
        setTimeout(captureToCanvas, 500);    
        return;
    }
    var n=navigator;
    document.getElementById("outdiv").innerHTML = vidhtml;
    v=document.getElementById("v");

    if(n.getUserMedia)
        n.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, success, error);
    else
    if(n.webkitGetUserMedia)
    {
        webkit=true;
        n.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true, audio: false}, success, error);
    }
    else
    if(n.mozGetUserMedia)
    {
        moz=true;
        n.mozGetUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, success, error);
    }

    //document.getElementById("qrimg").src="qrimg2.png";
    //document.getElementById("webcamimg").src="webcam.png";
    document.getElementById("qrimg").style.opacity=0.2;
    document.getElementById("webcamimg").style.opacity=1.0;

    stype=1;
    setTimeout(captureToCanvas, 500);
}
function setimg()
{
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
    if(stype==2)
        return;
    document.getElementById("outdiv").innerHTML = imghtml;
    //document.getElementById("qrimg").src="qrimg.png";
    //document.getElementById("webcamimg").src="webcam2.png";
    document.getElementById("qrimg").style.opacity=1.0;
    document.getElementById("webcamimg").style.opacity=0.2;
    var qrfile = document.getElementById("qrfile");
    qrfile.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);  
    qrfile.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);  
    qrfile.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
    stype=2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to JavaScript, may you long prosper with its many uses!

As you are new to JavaScript, you may not know its Browser API, but fear not!

What you are looking for is `window.open`

Its syntax is simple:

```
window.open("http://example.com")
```

So, when you get the url from you qr decoder, all you have to do is `window.open` the URL, and viola, the window will appear in a new tab!

Now if you want to open in the same browser window, then you want to use

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com")
```

This will redirect the *same* tab, instead of a new one!

To implement this in your program, take a look at this `read` function:

```
function read(a) {
  // If it's a URL, open in here
  if(a.indexOf("http://") === 0 || a.indexOf("https://") === 0)
    window.location.replace(a)
}
```

Hope I could help!

Comment: Thanks for your reaction!!! I think I understand what you mean. Only I don't understand how to implement it in the webQR.js? Do I need to add it in the: function read(a) ?

Comment: Ok, I'll walk you through the implementation in an edit